# Extremely slow when clearing all filters on a sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, autofilter, vba

I don't understand why this is taking so long to complete, strangely enough it takes the most time in executing "ActiveSheet.ShowAllData". Can anyone suggest what may improve it?

```
Sub ClearAllFilters()
  Application.Calculation = xlManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

For Each OleObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If OleObj.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
        OleObj.Object = False
    End If
    Next

Sheets("Manhour Summary Current Month").TextBox1.Text = ""
Sheets("Manhour Summary Current Month").TextBox2.Text = ""
Sheets("Manhour Summary Current Month").TextBox3.Text = ""

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$H$1307").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>0"

     End If
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Basically I'm clearing all autofilters, clearing a checkbox and clearing three textboxes.
This is for ~1000 rows of data, so it's nothing excessive I would've thought!

Thank you!

---

The problem was with conditional formatting applied to the majority of cells. I'm astounded that it's such a problem to have autofilters and conditional formatting.

Massive thank you for all your help! My head feels a lot better now....

Comment: because you are doing 4(3) different things here debug.print timestamps for each operation and tell us which one takes the most amount of time to execute.

Comment: or On Error Resume Next ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error Goto 0

Comment: Or remove the filter and put it back again and see how much time does that take...

Comment: What is the time if you do this manually?

Comment: It's not for me to use, it's for managers who aren't proficient with Excel. It is making my sheet completely unusable and it's very frustrating! Perhaps I should cull out any sensitive data and upload the sheet? This is driving me insane!

Thank you all for your help, but unfortunately nothing seems to have helped. Maybe I'm using too many formulae (~38k cells) summarising everyone's timesheets. But really? If Excel 2010 can't handle this I'd be very surprised!

Comment: Here's a screengrab of my sheet. Please note each spreadsheet only covers one months worth of information (~38k cells using IF, VLOOKUP, and OFFSET formulae). [http://bit.ly/10D4p9l] When I clear the filters manually it takes a lot of time as well, so I don't think VBA is the problem, but as I said, I'd be shocked if this was a bit too much for Excel to handle! My machine isn't massively powerful but it should be able to handle this surely! –

Comment: I have the same problem as you except Excel 2010 was fine and Excel 2013 has turned sour. Probably because I went from 2010 x64 to 2013 x32. Funny thing for me is I can change the filter (ie if I filter by one account manager and change to another it is fast) but as soon as I want to clear the filter it either takes 5 minutes or it is non responsive and I have to force close Excel and try again. ARGH!!!! I wish I could do this stuff in Ruby instead :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False` and I'd be interested to see if this improve things.

**added performance potential:**

1. If the opportunity is there flattering your formulas is ideal as you have so many.
2. If these are required but you can update at request, say when times are updated, then a trick I've learnt is keep the first row as formulas but flatten the rest and when the data is updated then copy these formulas down, update the values and then re-flatten all but the first row again.
3. Alternative to the above is to create a procedure that updates these values and have this run when needed and have no formulas at all.

**Post conditional formatting issue:**

1. As a way to improve due to conditional formatting you could have the sheet change the cell format once data has been updated via VBA instead. This will reduce excel doing this every time you filter.
2. Also and possibly **my favourite** due to your circumstances is to have your dates display the day, say `Sat 2-Mar-13`. This will still give the quick check of a weekend and improve performance.

Comment: It's really frustrating. It seems to run fast the first time I open the spreadsheet, from thereon it takes forever.

Comment: Just tried that out funnily enough - did a paste values and there was no improvement. It's really confusing as I'm using exactly the same filters and search functions on a separate tab that summarises the timesheet comments (~32k cells, also using using IF, VLOOKUP, and OFFSET formulae) and it runs perfect! Almost instant results! What could be going wrong? I've spent so long getting it to this point and they're keen to use it but I can't issue it with these problems.

Thanks again  :)

Comment: It sounds like a dumb question but is there anything different in this sheet? Like a code that executes on every cell change or another workbook open at the same time? Also, not ideal, but what about starting again with a rudimentary and rough try on another sheet or workbook to eliminate other factors? Like I said, not ideal. What an issue. :'(

Comment: I'm glad you understand my frustrations! : |  There's absolutely nothing different about the way the other sheet works - but you've made a good suggestion thank you. I'll completely rebuild the sheet that is causing all this ruddy heartache and see if that fixes it. What have I got to lose? : )

Comment: Mein gott... I may have found out why. Conditional formatting is on every cell on the right hand side. Argh - it's purely so we can differentiate between weekends and weekdays, so it's not ESSENTIAL, but it'd be REALLY handy. Any suggestions? Is this something that cannot be optimised?

Comment: So it worked faster without these? And is there an option to do this via vba as a once off and not conditionally?

Comment: Infinitely faster. Considering I'm only doing one month per spreadsheet I think I'll spend the extra 20 seconds and manually highlight Saturday and Sunday - and I'll try that code to highlight any entries with 10 hours or more soon. You sir, are a legend.